# OpenCV: measuring distance between two balls in millimeters - how to improve accuracy

Tags: opencv

I also posted this topic in the Q&A forum at opencv.org but I don't know how many experts from here are reading this forum - so forgive me that I'm also trying it here.

I'm currently learning OpenCV and my current task is to measure the distance between two balls which are lying on a plate. My next step is to compare several cameras and resolutions to get a feeling how important resolution, noise, distortion etc. is and how heavy these parameters affect the accuracy. If the community is interested in the results I'm happy to share the results when they are ready! The camera is placed above the plate using a wide-angle lens. The width and height of the plate (1500 x 700 mm) and the radius of the balls (40 mm) are known.

My steps so far:

1. camera calibration
2. undistorting the image (the distortion is high due to the wide-angle lens)
3. findHomography: I use the corner points of the plate as input (4 points in pixels in the undistorted image) and the corner points in millimeters (starting with 0,0 in the lower left corner, up to 1500,700 in the upper right corner)
4. using HoughCircles to find the balls in the undistorted image
5. applying perspectiveTransform on the circle center points => circle center points now exist in millimeters
6. calculation the distance of the two center points: d = sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2)

The results: an error of around 4 mm at a distance of 300 mm, an error of around 25 mm at a distance of 1000 mm But if I measure are rectangle which is printed on the plate the error is smaller than 0.2 mm, so I guess the calibration and undistortion is working good.

I thought about this and figured out three possible reasons:

1. findHomography was applied to points lying directly on the plate whereas the center points of the balls should be measured in the equatorial height **=> how can I change the result of findHomography to change this, i.e. to "move" the plane? The radius in mm is known.**
2. the error increases with increasing distance of the ball to the optical center because the camera will not see the ball from the top, so the center point in the 2D projection of the image is not the same as in the 3D world - I will we projected further to the borders of the image. **=> are there any geometrical operations which I can apply on the found center to correct the value?**
3. during undistortion there's probably a loss of information, because I produce a new undistorted image and go back to pixel accuracy although I have many floating point values in the distortion matrix. **Shall I search for the balls in the distorted image and tranform only the center points with the distortion matrix? But I don't know what's the code for this task.**

I hope someone can help me to improve this and I hope this topic is interesting for other OpenCV-starters.

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are some thoughts to help you along... By no means "the answer", though.

First a simple one. If you have calibrated your image in mm at a particular plane that is distance D away, then points that are `r` closer will appear larger than they are. To get from measured coordinates to actual coordinates, you use

```
Actual = measured * (D-r)/D
```

So since the centers of the spheres are radius `r` above the plane, the above formula should answer part 1 of your question.

Regarding the second question: if you think about it, the center of the sphere that you see should be in the right place "in the plane of the center of the sphere", even though you look at it from an angle. Draw yourself a picture to convince yourself this is so.

Third question: if you find the coordinates of the spheres in the distorted image, you should be able to transform them to the corrected image using [`perspectiveTransform`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20perspectiveTransform(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20m)). This may improve accuracy a little bit - but I am surprised at the size of errors you see. How large is a single pixel at the largest distance (1000mm)?

**EDIT**

You asked about elliptical projections etc. Basically, if you think of the optical center of the camera as a light source, and look at the shadow of the ball onto the plane as your "2D image", you can draw a picture of the rays that just hit the sides of the ball, and determine the different angles:

[image]

It is easy to see that P (the mid point of A and B) is not the same as C (the projection of the center of the sphere). A bit more trig will show you that the error `C - (A+B)/2` increases with `x` and decreases with `D`. If you know A and B you can calculate the *correct* position of C (given D) from:

```
C = D * tan( (atan(B/D) + atan(A/D)) / 2 )
```

The error becomes larger as D is smaller and/or x is larger. Note D is the perpendicular (shortest) distance from the lens to the object plane.

This only works if the camera is acting like a "true lens" - in other words, there is no pincushion distortion, and a rectangle in the image plane maps into a rectangle on the sensor. The above combined with your own idea to fit in the uncorrected ('pixel') space, then transform the centers found with `perspectiveTransform`, ought to get you all the way there.

See what you can do with that!

Comment: Thank you very much! Your first hint has a huge impact on the error. I'm not where the test setup currently is, but I know that the plate is around 1200 mm away from the camera, so I used your formular to correct the x and y values of the circle centers and: the error now is only 0.3 mm instead of 25 mm! I will improve circle detection (sub-pixel corner, contours, etc.) and measure the real distance and then my problem is solved!!! Sorry, can not vote up (no enough reputation)

Comment: Well I'm glad it was that easy! Don't worry about upvoting. Best thing you can do is keep asking questions, then start answering them. This is a "pay it forward" community... Of course you are allowed to accept an answer (check mark) even though you can't upvote it. Feel free to wait and see if any better answers come along though.

Comment: I now did some more testing. I used your formular to correct the measured coordinates (after step 5). The distance between two balls which are lying on the left and the right border is now 1000 mm, nearly without any error (1000.000016). But what I expected: the x-coordinate of the left ball should be around "0" because it directly lies on the border which I used to initialize findHomography. But I get -9.9.. for the left and 990... for the right ball. The distance is correct, but all coordinates seem to be shiftet to the left...any idea why this happens? Thanks again!

Comment: "Lies directly on the border" - you mean it _looks_ from the camera like it lies on the border. Is your camera centered above the middle of the rectangle, or off to the side? You are using (0,1000) as the edges. Thus the center is at 500mm. When you transform the center with my formula, it ends up shifted too...

Comment: The camera is centered above the plate...you are right, when I set -500 and 500 as the x-coordinates the position is close to 0. My next step is to detect the balls accuratly - HoughCircles doesn't find the center at sub-pixel-accuracy and it seems to be better to use findContours and fitEllipse because the ball with a large offset to the optical center is clearly an ellipse

Comment: When a sphere is projected obliquely onto a plane, the center of the ellipse DOES NOT CORRESPOND to the center of the sphere. The math for this is a little bit tricky - draw yourself three lines from a point to the center of the sphere and touching the two extremes- where they intersect with the plane below, they are no longer equidistant. For accurate results at low angles this is an important correction. Will try to give equation tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, I think so, too. This is what I wanted to say with problem nr. 2 in my original post. I tried to figure out an equation for this and read several papers, for example [this one](http://www.mie.utoronto.ca/labs/ciml/projects/rob_vision/Tony.pdf), Chapter 2, but it's too tricky for me. I would be very grateful for your help again!

Comment: One more - maybe interesting - information: in the undistorted image the ellipses are more clearly visible than in the original image. In the original image the balls are nearly a circle. If I use the center points in the original image: do they correspond better to the real center of the sphere? I then would apply the undistortion to the center points only, then perspectiveTransform and then your first formular. Does this make sense?

Comment: Your suggestion makes sense. See also my edit to original answer.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much!!! I will start testing tomorrow. I think I will try to find A and B in the undistorted image, the use perspektiveTransform, and then use your formula... I'm not sure which is the best workflow, but I will find out :-)